# How to get multiple lines of input in Python (for programming problem)?

Tags: python-3.x

In a programming problem, I receive inputs like this:

```
6
7
8
5
4
```

And I want to create a list like [6, 7, 8, 5, 4] in this case, that is, a list of the numbers in the input.

I tried reading directly from input but then I printed my list and found out it was [6], so it only read the first line.

```
lst = []
    while True:
        n = input()
        if n != '':
            lst.append(int(n))
        else: 
            break
    print(lst)
```

This gives me an EOF error.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe a bit better your settings, e.g. how are you receiving your input? where are you getting EOF error? If I run your code (after fixing the indentation) in the REPL, everything works just fine.

Comment: I don't know how I'm receiving my input. All I know is I take it with input(), as I have done in the past with other programming problems. Here is the problem. https://www.techgig.com/practice/question/candies-to-children/dTV4dFVRdVVXUTUyODV3Q0xDZENDRzkvRFhKQTY1VUd1Qlo1R2RrK0tDVT0=/1. I get the EOF error after running that code.

Comment: I am thinking this is an indentation error. Just ran the code [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler) after fixing the indentation and it worked as expected

Comment: Can you please try receiving the input from the problem in the link above? I don't think the indentation is the issue.

Comment: @Archsys the link above does not work in my country, but this [here](https://repl.it/repls/LightyellowBigheartedLoopfusion) work without issues.

Comment: Ah, I cannot access that link.

Comment: @norok2 's link work for me too no problems...

Comment: "This gives me an EOF error" That's the point. Catch it and react appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try-except` block

```
lst = []
while True:
    try:
        n = input()
        lst.append(int(n))
    except EOFError:
        break
print(lst)
```